# Interclassing 2 sorted files on different columns

Tags: sorting, awk, merge

I have 2 (really huge) sorted files like these:

```
==> date1 <==
1 A
2 A
5 A
7 A

==> date2 <==
B 2
B 4
B 5
B 5
B 6
B 8
```

and I need the following output:

```
1 A
2 A
B 2
B 4
5 A
B 5
B 5
B 6
7 A
B 8
```

So i need to merge 2 files according 2 different columns, by inter-classing lines from 2 files.

I try with `sort -m`, but as far as i can understand we can't specify different columns for each file.
I also try with awk and the FNR==NR trick, but file are too big for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat f1
1 A
2 A
5 A
7 A

$ cat f2
B 2
B 4
B 5
B 5
B 6
B 8

$ sort -nk1 -k2 f1 <(awk '{print $2,$1,"*"}' f2) | awk '/*/{print $2,$1; next}1' 
1 A
2 A
B 2
B 4
5 A
B 5
B 5
B 6
7 A
B 8
```

Comment: this work only if my line doesn't contain "*", which is not the case (I don't know which character are on my line, so I assume that all character can be on the line, sorry if it was not clear)

Comment: @robertd: It works for given input, while creating post please post data which is identical to your real input, so that yours and others (who come here to help) time can be saved, and meanwhile you will get what you want